# Exclude a library inside dependency Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, gradle, build.gradle

I am a beginner Android developer, I am developing an Android application that includes the OpenCV library as below:

[image]

My application also needs a library (named LibA) but it also contains Opencv:

[image]

When I build an application I got error message

> Type org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$3 is defined multiple times: D:\SourceCode\ABC\openCVLibrary42\build.transforms\096e4eb455c1b3f91f1eb28987c7a730\transformed\release\org\opencv\android\AsyncServiceHelper$3.dex, D:\SourceCode\ABC\app\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\release\mergeExtDexRelease\classes2.dex

I tried to exclude Opencv in LibA as below but it doesn't work

```
    implementation ('com.ceco.library:library-temp:2.0.5-SNAPSHOT'){
    exclude module: 'org.opencv'
    }
```

This is dependencies of LibA

```
  com.ceco.library:library-temp:2.0.5-SNAPSHOT
 +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.3.50 -> 1.6.0 (*)
 +--- com.guide:guidecore:v2.5.3
 +--- com.ceco.library:library-card:1.0.7-SNAPSHOT
 |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0
 |    |    +--- com.squareup.okio:okio:2.8.0 (*)
 |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10 -> 1.6.0 (*)
 |    +--- com.squareup.okio:okio:2.8.0 (*)
 |    +--- com.github.angads25:filepicker:1.1.1
 |    +--- net.grandcentrix.tray:tray:0.12.0
 |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0 -> 1.3.0
 |    \--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0 -> 1.4.1 (*)
 \--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0 -> 1.4.1
```

This is my app/build.gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    ....
    // Others
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation project(path: ':openCVLibrary42')
    //
    implementation 'com.ceco.library:library-temp:2.0.5-SNAPSHOT'

}
```

How can I resolve the above problem?

Comment: Hi @Zappy could you clarify if you know where opencv is included as a dependency again? Or ist the library-temp the only dependency you know where opencv is used? Is it possible to share the complete build.gradle file?

Comment: Hi @David, updated the question. Could you help me?

Comment: Hi @Zappy would it be a problem for you to remove your own opencv reference and use the one included in the LibA dependency?